# Google empty comment in search json

Tags: javascript, json, google-search

I was looking at the json Google search is doing when I type at the searchbar at google.com.
The url and full example contains many unique ID's, so I wont post them, but you can see this by yourself by using firebug or the built in Chrome developer tool and look at the network tab.

Shortened and prettyfied, the json looks like:

```
{
    e:"QsbL...",
    c:0,
    u:"https://www.google.no/s?gs_rn\x3d3...086251360.1",
    p:true,
    d:"[...]"
}/*""*/
```

What is the last `/*""*/` part useful for?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply an empty comment, maybe used for debug by the google developers.

If you need to manipulate with google search engine, use the proper tools:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview

Comment: Might be.. But I still think it is weird to leave that in when they are trying to minimize everything. If an average search is 10 characters, this little thing wastes over 10GiB in bandwidth every hour. Not that I think it matters for Google... Maybe this protects against some weird kind of attack. Like why they have an while true loop wrapped around their api some places..

Comment: @xeor In effect your objection is interesting. I tried to search around some informations, but no infos... What is strange is that comments like that are not a standard JSON notation for comments, they seems more like javascript.